# CSS isn't updating past my index.html within VS Code for Mac

Tags: html, css, macos

Trying to complete a recipe assignment for Odin Project and I'm unable to get my instruction page to show the same formatting as my index once my CSS stylesheet is linked

**Index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Odin Recipes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Odin Recipes</h1>
        <img src="https://thefader-res.cloudinary.com/private_images/w_640,c_limit,f_auto,q_auto:eco/Food_Makes_Me_Happy_with_Lil_B_csngyg/lil-b-cooking-show-food-makes-me-happy-colin-tilley.jpg" alt="Lil' B">
        <h2>A Beautiful List of Tantelizing Bangers</h2>
    <ul>
   <li><a href="recipes/braisedbeefandtortellini.html">Braised Beef and Tortellini</a></li>
   <li><a href="recipes/carbonara.html">Carbonara</a></li>
   <li><a href="recipes/orzo.html">Mushroom and Chicken Orzo</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Style.css**

```
body {
    background-color: khaki;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 50px 0px 100px 20px;
}

img {
   height:600px;
   width:400px;
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

p,ol,ul {
    text-align: center;
}

h1,h2,h3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

`

**First Recipe**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Braised Beef and Tortellini</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/odin-recipes/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
       <h1>Braised Beef and Tortellini</h1>
       <img src="https://assets.change.org/photos/8/ym/fy/IKyMfYAeynyNQMq-800x450-noPad.jpg?1622493392">
       <h1>Description</h1>
       <p>This restaurant quality Braised Beef and Tortellini is loaded with tender chunks of beef in the most <strong><em>amazing</em></strong> Marsala wine sauce, and spooned over Asiago cheese tortelloni.</p>
        <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>3 pounds short ribs, bone left on</li>
            <li>1 teaspoon kosher salt</li>
            <li>1/2 teaspoon of freshly grounded pepper</li>
            <li>3 tablespoons extra virgin olive oil</li>
            <li>1 cup sweet diced onions</li>
            <li>1/4 cup fresh basil, chopped, plus more for garnish</li>
            <li>1 cup Marsala wine (do not use the Marsala cooking wine from the supermarket, get real Marsala drinking wine)</li>
            <li>1 1/2 cups of beef stock</li>
            <li>1 cup water</li>
            <li>1 bay leaf</li>
            <li>2 large portabella mushroom caps</li>
            <li>2 plum tomatoes</li>
            <li>1 tablespoon basalmic vinegar</li>
            <li>2 tablespoons butter</li>
            <li>3 tablespoons flour</li>
            <li>1/4 cup heavy cream</li>
            <li>1 20-ounce package Asiago-filled fresh tortellini</li>
        </ul>
    <h3>Instructions</h3>
    <ol>
        <li>Preheat oven to 375 degrees F.</li>
        <li>Salt and pepper all sides of short rib</li>
        <li>In a large Dutch oven or heavy bottomed oven proof pot with an oven proof lid, heat the olive oil over medium high heat.</li>
        <li>Add the short ribs and sear on all six sides for 2-3 minutes per side. Remove the seared meat to a platter and pour off all but two tablespoons of the fat remaining in the pan but do not discard the remaining fat. More will be used later in this recipe.</li>
        <li>Add the onions and sauté for three minutes. Add the basil and cook for one more minute then add the Marsala wine.</li>
        <li>Reduce by half then add the beef stock, water and the bay leaf and add the seared ribs back into the pan. The liquid will not cover the tops of the beef. Cover and place in the oven for two hours, untouched.</li>
        <li>While the short rib is braising, in a large skillet, add 2 tablespoons of the reserved beef fat and once hot, add the mushrooms. Sauté for 5-6 minutes or until tender.</li>
        <li>Add the tomatoes, cook for one minute then add the balsamic vinegar. Cook for one more minute and remove from heat. Set aside.</li>
        <li>After two hours, remove the pot from the oven and pick the beef pieces out to your cutting board with tongs. The bones should slip right off and be discarded. Once they are cool enough to handle, use a sharp knife and remove fat and gristle from the beef.  Cut the remaining beef pieces against the grain into slices.</li>
        <li>Place a large pot of water on to cook the tortelloni while you finish the dish. The tortellini takes about 6-7 minutes to cook, assuming you are using fresh.</li>
        <li>In a small sauté pan, melt butter and once melted, add flour. Cook for three minutes over medium heat and then remove from heat.</li>
        <li>Heat the liquid left in the pot of beef over medium high and once it starts to boil, add the butter and flour mixture and whisk to combine. Once thickened, add heavy cream and whisk again. Add cooked sliced beef and cooked mushrooms and tomatoes from earlier. Stir to combine.</li>
        <li>Drain the cooked tortelloni and add back into the pot it was cooked in and add a little of the finished sauce to coat.</li>
        <li>Pour the tortelloni into a serving platter and pour the finished braised beef over the top.</li>
        <li>Garnish with some chopped fresh basil and enjoy this beautiful dish!</li>
     </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Updated my style.css with colors, etc and only my index.html is updating and not the other html filed that's linked.

Comment: I don't know the whole folder structure but I believe the link in your pages is not finding style.css, try adding .. to exit current folder as ../style.css inside recipes and review vscode path suggestions

Comment: thanks a bunch for your help! the folder structures below:

repos/odin-recipes/style.css

i played around with your suggestion before asking the question but still unsure what the issue is :(

Comment: hmm, maybe it could be cache, try disabling browser cache

Comment: works in chrome, i was opening the .htm file within safari for a preview ._. thanks so much for your help!